# I'm trying to connect to google API, but safari can't connect to localhost

Tags: api, google-drive-api

I'm tying to use google drive API. I am now trying to connect to google API using the code below, but in the process, safari can't connect to local host. I tried to change 'redirect_uris'to 127.0.0.1 but didn't work.. Code is from YouTube. Thank you.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']


def main():
    
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
    
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is from credential.json file. I think it is related..

```
"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://127.0.0.1"]}}
```

thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the [Drive API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) and follow the steps there, specifically the prerequisites and the [Credential Creation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials).

Ultimately, the **credential.json** file is something that has to be downloaded from the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and that, well, verifies your credentials.